# NameError: name 'ttk' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror, ttk

trying to create a combobox, follow a tutorial on youtube from 2016 on making a currency calculator for my school work.

```
box = ttk.Combobox(LeftMainFrame, textvariable=value0, state='readonly',font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),width=20)
box['values'] = (' ', 'USA', 'Kenya', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'India', 'Phillappines')
box.current(0)
box.grid(row=4, column=2)
```

keeps saying ttk is not defined.

I know nothing about python
I am also using visual studio

Comment: The convention is to use `tk` as shorthand for Tkinter, not `ttk`. Can you share the `import` statements in your script?

Comment: It was                                                                                              from tkinter import *
import time
import datetime I then changes it too                                                  from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import time
import datetime                  and I think that fixed but now I have an error for _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bd"

Comment: You must import the ttk package before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

From [python's ttk doc (python 2)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#using-ttk), or [same for python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tkinter.ttk.html?highlight=ttk):

> To start using Ttk, import its module:

```
import ttk
```

> But code like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

> may optionally want to use this:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
```

> And then several ttk widgets (Button, Checkbutton, Entry, Frame, Label, LabelFrame, Menubutton, PanedWindow, Radiobutton, Scale and Scrollbar) will automatically substitute for the Tk widgets.

So, depending on your environment, you may have to import ttk:

```
import ttk
```